# ORACLE wm_concat equivalent in PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.2

I'm new to PostgreSQL and I have a problem migrating databases from Oracle to PostgreSQL 9.2. I must change some native queries in my code. I have a subquery like:

```
SELECT wm_concat(p.first_name || ' ' || p.last_name) 
FROM TODO_PERSON PR 
JOIN PERSON P ON (p.id == pr.person_id)
WHERE todo_id = internal_table.id
```

In PostgreSQL I can't find equivalent function or other solutions ...

Comment: Are you sure your code works in Oracle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostgreSQL has a bunch of available [aggregation functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html).

`wm_concat` equivalent seems to be `string_agg`, except you *must* specify the delimiter. Please, check the documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent is **string_agg**.

*i.e.: "show me the list of the orders for each customer"*

```
SELECT customer_id, string_agg(order_id, ',') 
FROM order 
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Answer (score -1):

It's just simple concatenation. You can either use CONCAT function or write the query just with pipes;

So first solution would be:

```
SELECT CONCAT(p.first_name, ' ', p.last_name) [...]
```

or:

```
SELECT p.first_name || ' ' || p.last_name [...]
```

If you want to add commas to the results just add commas instead of gap, as a string between column names. i.e.:

SELECT CONCAT(p.first_name, ', ', p.last_name) [...]

The very last part of your query is quite mysterious. What are you using those brackets for?

Comment: [`wm_concat` is an undocumented aggregate function in Oracle.](http://psoug.org/definition/WM_CONCAT.htm)

Comment: wm_concat is an aggregate function - to this answer is not related to what was initially asked.